# App downloading restrictions

Tags: android

Developing an app to help employees within the company. I would like to restrict it so that only poeple from my company can download it. Is this possible, or could I make it password protected on the first use, then have it unlocked?

Comment: Simple don't upload it in google. Upload it in your intranet server(If any) else mail them a copy. :)

Comment: are there instructios in FAQ here on how to do that? Didn't know you could E-mail it. Company server is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Google Play Private Channel](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-new-way-to-distribute-your-internal.html). This is available to you if you are a Google Apps for Business, Education, or Government customer.